# Name for functions with local=global minimum

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, terminology, convex-optimization, global-optimization

I have a simple question. We know that functions where every stationary point is a global minimum are invex functions. Is there a name for functions where every local minimum is a global minimum?

And also can we naturally put convex functions into this scheme? As I see, claiming that it has only one global minimum that is the only stationary point is not enough.

Thank you!

Also, there is no tag for invexity

Comment: you are thinking of a function which is not convex and yet every local minimum is a global minimum?

Comment: There days people are calling such functions: "functions without bad local minima", though I must admit, that is not much of name :-)

Comment: @Carlo yes, it can be very crazy

Comment: @Suvrit I like the phrase actually

Comment: Are you asking for coercive functions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function

Comment: @Henry.L, since only the boundary behaviour is constrained, it seems that such functions can have multiple internal local minima that are not global minima.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, but that is my closest guess...By a definitive name you are asking for a sufficient/necessary condition.

Comment: When local≠global minimum, the local minimum has been called as "spurious local minimum". See for instance the arXiv pre-prints [1605.07272](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07272) and [1704.00708](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00708).

Comment: On a side note, I think that we should restrain ourselves a little from creating artificial neologisms by analogy. By the way, the compound *in-veho* does exist in Latin, and the English word *invective* is a derivation of it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a specific term that describes this property, but it is different from convexity and invexity:

This function has a single global mimumum, but it has multiple stationary points, and therefore it is not invex:

$$
f(x) = 3 x^4 - 4 x^3
$$

> And also can we naturally put convex functions into this scheme?

For a convex function, a local minumum will also be global.

However, the inverse is not true. A function may have only one local minimum, but be non-convex, for example

$$
f(x) = - e^{-x^2}
$$

is not convex, but has only one local minumum (and also a single stationary point)